# Django: How to periodically and asynchronously publish new data to the respective client

Tags: python, django, redis

Following is a sequence of events that is happening

Part 1:

- Client sends a form.
- Django receives a form, validates it and creates a Task for Celery or Django-rq to run.
- Returns results.html to the user.

Part 2:

- Task is run by the workers which generates JSON data every second.
- This needs to be sent to the right client asynchronously and as a part of result.html.
- Client should see the updated results without doing any refresh.

How do I solve this?

After some amount of research following are some of the ways I thought of:

1. Write the updated data to the Database and have Django poll it with a scheduler. Not really sure how I can send it to the right client.
2. Have the client subscribe for events and use django-websocket-redis to publish the data. I'm not sure if this is possible because each client requires a unique websocket to subscribe to and I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: First -> read what `HTTP long polling` is. Second - `websockets` will be harder to implement and maintain but a better solution from perfomance point of view. Third - prepare to write a lot of JS too.

Comment: Can you not filter your data to return on a per-user basis?

Comment: The users need not be logged in, they can open multiple tabs and request for service.  The data should go to the right channel